# Showing network activity indicator when status bar is hidden in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, ios6, ios7

I am developing an IOS game. As in many IOS games, I hide the status bar and never show it at any point. My app includes a feature to download new application data stored in moderately large files on my server. The problem is: how do I indicate network activity to the user when downloading is in progress? The standard approach is to display the network activity indicator in the status bar, but the status bar is hidden in my app. Of course, I want to conform to Apple User Interface Guidelines and pass the App Store review process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you show a loader element inside the app? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was concerned that not displaying the official network activity indicator would be a user interface guidelines violation, but  it seems there's ample precedent. It seems there's not much to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I sure you can choose any way to inform user about that. But you should also update standard indicator because it becomes visible when your app becomes hidden (if you want to download in background).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the network activity indicator becoming visible while the app is in the background.